# How should I be calculating monster CR when the min & max HP give different CRs?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, cr-calculation

I'm programming a tool to help with monster building. [I'm leaning a lot on the angry GM](http://theangrygm.com/monster-building-202/)

The features *Undead Fortitude* and *Relentless* adjust HP by a static amount. As I am calculating defensive CR, I'd like to factor that HP bump into the CR calculation. Since HP at each tier of CR is given as a range, I'm curious how others would handle that calculation.

*I'm sorry if I get some of the below numbers wrong, I don't have my books right now*

A CR 4 monster has 116-132 HP. These traits above increase HP by 7[ish] at this level. Adding 7 to 116 HP is still a CR 4 monster. Adding 7 to 132 is a CR 5.

The only way I can think to resolve this is to decide starting defensive CR and monster size, calculate hit dice and what the average HP would be for that CR and that monster size, then apply the trait bonus and see if that HP increase bumps the monster into the next level of CR.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the specific question you are asking and am unsure how to edit to better clarify. Can you relook at this and rephrase? I think you're asking about how to handle the CR bump that happens by the application of these features, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Nate, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Right now your question reads to me as *"if I add some HP in some circumstance, the CR might not get bumped up. I might solve that [unstated] problem this way, how would you do it?"* The issue is there doesn't actually seem to be a problem or question here in anything you've described, so there's nothing for us to solve or answer -- sometimes extra HP *just doesn't* bump CR up, and that's how it's meant to work. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: [Here's the proposed edit I think you're referencing](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34452). I believe it was rejected since we couldn't be sure it was representative of your words and intentions, and editing your question to be asking something you're not interested in asking wouldn't have been appropriate and helpful.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think my edit clarified what I'm asking.

Comment: @Nate Thanks for taking the time to edit that stuff. I've given it an edit -- does this reflect what you're going for? (If not, feel free to edit it further or roll it back.)

Comment: @doppelgreener yes this reflects what I'm looking for.

Comment: Even editted, what's the question here?

Comment: @daze413 At first I was looking for an answer about how to calculate, then it kind of turned into what do people think, now I've decided how I'm going to do it so there really isn't a question anymore.

Comment: @NateAnderson It's ethical in this site to self-answer (we even have a badge for it!) if you found your answer. You can still edit to show the question you were originally asking then post an answer yourself. Then, we can maybe help you clarify the question in light of your self-answer